# Read jpeg file to char* buffer c

Tags: c, buffer, jpeg

I'm trying to read a jpeg file into a char* buffer so that I can print out the buffer as text. My problem is that I'm only reading the first line. Here's my code:

```
        FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "r");
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        unsigned long fileLen=ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char* file_data;
        file_data=(char *)malloc((fileLen+1)*sizeof(char));

        while (!feof(file)) {
            fread(file_data, fileLen, 1, file);
        }

        fclose(file);
        printf("%s\n", file_data);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file in binary mode "rb".

As mentioned above, doing a printf of binary jpeg data will not produce useful results.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is this

```
FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long fileLen=ftell(file);
char* file_data;
rewind(file);
file_data=malloc((fileLen)*sizeof(char));
if (file_data == NULL){
    printf("Memory error"); exit (2);
}
int num_read=0;
char s;
while ((num_read = fread(&s, 1, 1, file))) {
    strncat(file_data,&s,1);
}

printf("file contents: %s", file_data);
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `sizeof(char)` is `1`.
2. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.
3. Using `feof()` as a loop condition is almost always wrong. Check and use the result of `fread` instead.
4. A binary file's data is unlikely to be a C string. Printing it with `%s` won't work - write a loop and print each byte out using `%02x`, for example.

Comment: He should also be opening the file in binary mode (`"rb"`), unless he wants bytes to be (seemingly) randomly dropped or changed on some systems.

Comment: So do I need to malloc at all?

Comment: @CatLord, you can, but you don't need to. You could just read one byte at a time if you want.